# Line spacing in enotez package

Tags: endnotes

How is it possible to change the line spacing in end notes producted by enotez package, too wide for me? I adopt `list-style=plain`? And if I would chose `list-style=itemize` can I change the line spacing with `\itemsep` (or in another way) without it modifies all lists of my text? thanx

this is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{enotez}

\setenotez{
  list-name=,
  backref=true,
  list-style=plain
}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
{
format = \footnotesize ,
number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}
\let\footnote=\endnote


\begin{document}
Bla bla bla\footnote{bla bla}

Bla bla bla\footnote{bla bla}

Bla bla bla\footnote{bla bla}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

I'd like only to reduce line spacing between endnotes, for the font size is small and the line spacing, in my opinion, too wide

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be no “easy” interface for setting the `notes-sep` parameter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{enotez}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{notes-sep=0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setenotez{
  list-name=,
  backref=true,
  list-style=plain
}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
{
format = \footnotesize ,
number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}
\let\footnote=\endnote


\begin{document}
Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly working, thanx! Only, it seems to me a bit strange that the package author/mantainer doesn't provide for any option to set in a clear and direct way the line spacing...

Comment: @user41063 Do a feature request at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez

Comment: @user41063 TBH: the interface of the `enotez` package is far from ideal and would need a complete makeover... if I find the time some day...

Comment: maybe a request is useless, for I realize that package maintainer is reading us :) In any case, enotez is very usefull and better in respect that the old `endnotes`. Hoping you'll work at it soon! thanx

Comment: I realize now that there is a little trouble: if I use prof egreg code, `number = \textsuperscript{#1}`doesn't work. If I put `printendnoted[custom]` notes numbers appear correctly as textsuperscript, but the line spacing is again wide...

Comment: This works for me; but if you have `\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}` set for your book, as I did, you'll need to add `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` before `\printendnotes`. Sorta obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 3):

@user41063 Try some variant of this to see if it will solve your problem mentioned in comments under Answer1. Enotez is an excellent package and I hope @cgcnieder will keep it going. Output is as for answer 1 with enumitem will give you a bunch of other possibilities.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{aublistforenotez}{itemize}{1}%This is for my enotez macro (enotez it passes token manually to each one via \item[] if list mode profile)
\setlist[aublistforenotez]{parsep=-\parskip, itemsep=-\parskip, topsep=0pt}%can set itemsep negative - experiment as it seems to be bigger than 0 by default


\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{aubcustomlist}{list}
{
heading = \subsubsection*{#1},
format = \footnotesize,
number-format  = \normalfont,
number =  \enmark{#1},
%number = \textsuperscript{#1},
list-type = aublistforenotez
}

\setenotez{
  list-name=,
  backref=true,
  list-style=plain
}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

Bla bla bla\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\printendnotes[aubcustomlist]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanx for your proposal. Just another answer: if I'd like to have only the first line indentation, and in the following lines the width as well as in the text? How and what I've to set?